# Example project with a C++ COM client that talks to a C# COM server?

Tags: c#, com

I'm stuck: I just can't get my head around how to access C# methods from C++. I've got as far as working out that you need a COM server, but none of the code I've tried works.

Can anybody point me in the direction of a working project that demos how C++ can call methods from a C# library, using COM or otherwise?

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a sample with C++ calling managed code via COM [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2w30w8zx%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).  Also a two-part tutorial (somewhat dated) [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645712%28v=VS.71%29.aspx).

Play around a bit and come back with more detailed questions.

Comment: Thanks, with your help everything works well now. The problem was that I had to set the COM object to "visible" using "[assembly: ComVisible(true)]" in AssemblyInfo.cs.